# Software for communicating through google chrome (or any browser)

Tags: email, search, communication, gmail

I don't know if there is a way to do this, but I assume there is a hackish way (as there almost always is).

Say I am logged into Google Chrome using my gmail (and so all my web extensions, preferences, web history, etc. are loaded up into Chrome). Now, say I want to communicate with someone using the browser, but without explicitly visiting gmail.com or using a messaging extension. Is there a way to do this?

For example, is there a Chrome extension out there (or something like that) such that when I search something in Google, an email is automatically generated with that search term and sent out? This way I can communicate with that person, without visiting gmail.com or doing it explicitly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC), a browser-to-browser chat technology included in at least Firefox (and probably Chrome as well). Firefox used to have a built-in GUI for it called Hello, but that seems to have been removed. There is probably an extension that uses the built-in support for it, though.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page that you link to, it is supported from Google Chrome 28

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe you'll still need either an extension or a third-party website to actually use it, though. (There are websites that use WebRTC, or if you're a web developer, you can add it to your own site—see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API).)